# Javascript file loading error net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: javascript, web

My angular web page is having intermittent issues with loading the script files and the error in browser console says

https://mywebsite.com/resources/locales/bundle.js?locale=en&4.24.1.44-2b61a3b4 net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The network tab displays below with no HTTP status code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meeOZ.png)

I'm stuck with this and not sure where to look at. Any help directing me on figuring the cause would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.